# Syntax error in visualforce for date

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

What am I doing wrong?
If the date is less than today then it has to be red if it is greater than today then it should be green

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Expires</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold;color:{!if(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate < {!today()}, 'red', if(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate > {!today()},'green'))};" value="{!ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate}"/>                    
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: Can you include a larger portion of the code?  You are only showing a portion of the visualforce tag

Comment: Sorry you should see the entire code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra braces for `today()` in your expression.

Try this:

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Expires</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold;color:{!if(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate < today(), 'red', if(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate > today(),'green',''))};" value="{!ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate}"/>                    
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: Getting error " Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Text, received Date"

Comment: I'm assuming the `verboseWarrantyExpirationDate` returns a Date type.  Is that not correct?  What data type is it?

Comment: I defined it as string

Comment: Can you return it as date?  That will be needed to compare with `TODAY()`.  If you need to format the date, you can use a format string on the `outputText` component e.g. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm

Comment: If i want to keep it as integer how would i modify the line? i changed it to       "{!today()}" but still throwing error

Comment: Maybe you should post some of the controller code.  You said you are returning it as string and now you're asking if it can be Integer, so I'm a little confused.  The Visualforce `TODAY()` function returns a Date data type.  So that's the type you need if you want to compare.  see - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Comment: sorry i meant if i want to keep it as string not integer.                                public String verboseWarrantyExpirationDate {get;set;}

Comment: No.  You need it to be a date if you want to compare it to another Date.  You should not need to return it as a String.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25684/discussion-between-fehays-and-admin-ba).

Comment: Iam getting error "The value 'null' is not valid for operator '<'" how do we ignore if there is no date? iam returning null value so i need to ignore this condition

Comment: just add that check to your expression.  something like `<apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold;color:{!if(and(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate != null,ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate < today()),'red',if(and(ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate != null,ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate > today()),'green',''))};" value="{!ib.verboseWarrantyExpirationDate}"/>`